# C# nettcpbinding disable ntlm

Tags: c#, wcf, kerberos, ntlm

How to disable NTLM when connecting to WCF service? 
I want to be sure that Im using Kerberos, but there is no option on ChannelFactory in .netstandard20:

```
channelFactory.Credentials.Windows.AllowNtlm = false;
```

So currently Im unable to disable "fallback" to NTLM to check whether Kerberos even working.

Comment: Do you have admin access to your IIS server, IIS management tools? (where the WCF will be running)?

Comment: My server is self-hosted.

Comment: I've only managed that via IIS. "Authentication", { Digest Authentication, Windows Authentication }

Answer (score 0):

This is a deprecated attribute. `Kerberos` authentication will be used first as long as the server and client environments support `Windows Kerberos` authentication. If the machine environment on both sides is not supported, whether to downgrade to `NTLM` certification will be determined by the computer policy.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.security.windowsclientcredential.allowntlm?view=netframework-4.8
As the description said.

> This property is deprecated and is maintained for backward
>   compatibility only. The local machine policy will be used to determine
>   if NTLM should be used.

Here are some related links.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/network-security-restrict-ntlm-ntlm-authentication-in-this-domain
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/network-security-allow-local-system-to-use-computer-identity-for-ntlm
https://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2009/08/16/enabling-of-ntlm-on-windows-7-and-windows-server-2008-r2.aspx

Comment: The problem is my company policy will ban NTLM and I need to be sure to use Kerberos before that happens. If I accidently use NTLM because of this downgrade logic - my clients will be flooded with errors.